# Removing a custom object from an arraylist is returning false

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I have an array list made of of a custom object Profile. When a user clicks on an item in an array list the corresponding object is either added or removed to the tags array.

What is happening now is when a user clicks an item in the list, the checkbox will check and the item is added to the array, if the box is immediately unchecked by clicking again the object is removed fine from the tags array HOWEVER if the list is scrolled and get view is called again and the user then clicks a previously checked item tags.remove(profile) will return.

here is the adapter that extends a base adapter.

```
class TagAdapter extends StandardAdapter {

    boolean[] checkedItems;
    int iconWidth;

    public TagAdapter() {

        checkedItems = new boolean[items.size()];

        registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                updateProperties();
            }

        });

        iconWidth = MyApp.getScreenWidth() / 7;
    }

    void updateProperties() {
        checkedItems = new boolean[items.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkin_friend, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.ivIcon = (CachedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            viewHolder.cbFriend = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbFriend);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final JsonObject item = getItem(position);
        final Profile profile = new Gson().fromJson(item, Profile.class);

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(profile.getUsername());

        if (profile.getIcon() != null) {

            viewHolder.ivIcon.set(app.imageContainer + profile.getIcon(), true);

        }
        else {
            viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(app.defaultIcon);

        }

        viewHolder.ivIcon.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iconWidth, iconWidth));



        viewHolder.cbFriend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        viewHolder.cbFriend.setChecked(checkedItems[position]);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean current = checkedItems[position];

                if (current == true) {

                    boolean modified = tags.remove(profile);

                    if(modified == false){
                        Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"modification was false");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    tags.add(profile);
                }

                checkedItems[position] = !current;

                viewHolder.cbFriend.setChecked(checkedItems[position]);

                updateUi();

            }
        });



        return convertView;

    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        CachedImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvName;
        CheckBox cbFriend;
    }

}
```

The error is happening on the click listener on the convertview.

the variable tags is an arraylist composed of type Profile that is defined in its super class.

```
tags = new ArrayList<Profile>();
```

Comment: seems the "profile" is not that "profile" you push into `tags` once the list scrolls. Note  this line `final Profile profile = new Gson().fromJson(item, Profile.class);`

Comment: That's probably the reason but why, does the final modifier do something to the object comparison? in the getview method the object returned should be the same right? Or perhaps since it's reparsing the json the objects aren't identical

Comment: why the new `profile` would be the the same one? You use `new` so this is a new instance of profile. You should know that  "obja == objb" means the two are exactly the same object.